# Jest fails even if the expected and received object are same

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest for unit test for my backend(node.js). The test fails even if the expected and received are same. the following is the test case:.

My test file:

```
    const model= require('../../models/model');
     const Ctrl = require('../../controllers/controller');
        const mockRequest = (reqData) => {
            return {
              params: reqData.params? reqData.params:{} ,
              body: reqData.body?reqData.body:{}
            };
          };
        
          const mockResponse = () => {
            const res = {};
            res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
            res.json = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);    
            return res;
          };
    describe("...", () => {
         beforeAll(() => {
    
            const model1= new Model({
                _id:"5f23ba36b8cb543e4c6a8a30",
                Name:"abc"
            })
            const expectedArr = [];
            expectedArr.push(model1);
    Model.find = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(expectedArr)
    });
        test("it should return array ",  async () => {
            const model1= new Model({
                _id:"5f23ba36b8cb543e4c6a8a30",
                Name:"abc"            
            })
            const expectedArr = [];
            expectedArr.push(model1);
const resultObj = {"message":"2 ids fetched successfully.","a": expectedArr};
            expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(resultObj);
        });
    });
```

The above test is failing, but the test result is

```
- Expected
    + Received

    - {"a":[{}], "message": "2 ids fetched successfully."},
    + {"a":[{}], "message": "2 ids fetched successfully."}
```

But its fails. Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

**PS**

I am constructing data from model. Is that create issue??

**EDIT**
My model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Model', Schema );
```

Comment: Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with all the relevant code? toHaveBeenCalledWith already uses deep equality so there shouldn't be such error. It's unknown what resultObj is. You can also try `expect(res.json.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual({"a":[{}], "message": "2 ids fetched successfully."})` but I'd expect it to give the same result.

Comment: @Estus Flask Edited my post

Comment: Yes, this is potentially the issue. First of all, this is likely a bug in Jest because if it doesn't find differences in them, it should consider them equal. It was probably fixed in later Jest versions, more specifically `expect`. And it's likely caused by that an object is complex because it's a model (Mongoose?). The problem is in a way you test it and probably in a way the controller works. `res.json` is supposed to be called with plain object and not a model. If you have a model, convert it to plain object before sending. This way production code will give no surprises, so will tests.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you plz expain a bit more on `If you have a model, convert it to plain object before sending` how can i achieve this??

Comment: This totally depends on a model, you didn't specify what it is.

Comment: @Estus Flask Edited my post. Plz have a look.

Comment: See toJSON and toObject, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON . I assume `res.json` works as intended with Mongoose model because it implicitly converts it to plain object with `toJSON` when doing JSON.stringify. A more clean way that doesn't rely on Express internals is to convert it explicitly with `res.json(model.toObject())`. And I expect it to not have problems with toHaveBeenCalledWith.